# How to add MathJax to jekyll

Tags: jekyll, mathjax

I'm attempting to integrate MathJax into my Jekyll site to enable LaTeX formula rendering. I want to use `$` for inline formulas and `$$` for display formulas (formulas that appear on a separate line). I've been following [these instructions](https://www.bodunhu.com/blog/posts/add-mathjax-support-to-jekyll-and-hugo/), which recommend adding `{% include mathjax.html %}` to the `_includes/head.html` file just before the `</head>` tag. However, I don't have a `_includes/head.html` file. When I tried copying this file from the Minima theme repository (https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html), it resulted in broken CSS, likely due to dependencies on other CSS files. Additionally, my theme doesn't have a `_layouts` folder, so I'm unable to add the code to the header there, as there's no  tag to target.

UPD: I read a bit about this. Now I'm trying to create two files in     `_includes` folder.
`mathjax.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.1.2/es5/latest.js?tex-mml-chtml">
</script>
<script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
      displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ['\\[', '\\]']],
    },
    svg: {
      fontCache: 'global'
    }
  };
</script>
```

`custom-head.html`:

```
{%- include mathjax.html -%}
```

It still doesn't render formulas